# What is the Name of this Window Part

Tags: windows

I have double hung windows. The rectangular plastic piece in the middle of the image is on both sides of all my window sashes near the bottom and seems to act as a spacer. On completely different window the pieces have broken out so that window sash shifts left and right and the balance comes out the top.

Does anyone know the name of this plastic part and can it be replaced? I can find all the other parts like balances and cams. Not this though.

[image]

Comment: are you referring to the rectangle near the center of the picture?

Comment: Yes, it's plastic and all are completely dry rotted

Comment: it looks ok to me ... even the small hole in the middle still has undeteriorated edges

Comment: I sorry that I wasn't clear. This picture is of an unbroken one. The window in question is missing this on both sides. I need this part

Comment: please clarify your question ... use the [edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/284850/edit) button ... a comment is no place for important info

Answer (score 2):

It is a *sliding window face guide*.

You'll find it easier to shop for one if you have an unbroken one removed from its window, so you can see and measure the little clips that attach it.

I use the search tools at swisco.com to find door and window parts.  No affiliation, just a happy customer.  You can send them pictures of your part or, in this case I used their picture-based catalog to figure out what your thing is called.    Once you know what it's called, you use their regular search tool to find similar ones and similar queries from other customers.

I think it's [this](https://www.swisco.com/Face-Guide/pd/Channel-Balance-Sash-Clips_Pivots/67-026) and what we see in your photo compared to the one on the site is the reverse side of the left half.  You need to remove one and verify that or find the actual right one.